# static method in Python

Tags: python

I use static method in Python, like this:

```
class A(object):

    @staticmethod
    def sfun():
        print "this is statice method"

class AA(A):

    @staticmethod
    def sfun():
        print "this is statice method"
```

And I want to get type of class (A or AA) in sfun. How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. But if you use `classmethod` instead then the class will be passed as the first argument to the method.

```
class A(object):
  @classmethod
  def cfun(cls):
    print 'I am in %r' % (cls,)

class AA(A):
  pass
```